# Change color area with different transparencies

Tags: color, gimp, transparency

I have a picture which I need to edit, but everything I tried didn't work.

My picture has different transparencies but everything is the same color. I just want to change the color but the transparency of the unique pixels should stay the same.

Here is the picture so you can better understand my problem.
[image]

If you have a procedure that would solve my problem, please note that I am using gimp.

Comment: I thought about answering since you have that Adobe Photoshop tag but you did also say you're using Gimp... What a dilemma... I guess I'm not giving an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp:

- Set the "alpha-lock" for the layer (the checkerboard icon the the `Lock:` line at the top of the Layers list; when this is set, the opacity of pixels cannot change).

[image]

- bucket-fill with the new color.

[image]